# Cannot resolve symbol 'LargeTest'

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, testing-support-library

I am converting all of my tests over to the [Testing Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html). However, when I try to import the `LargeTest` annotation like this

```
import android.support.test.filters.LargeTest;
```

I get `Cannot resolve symbol 'LargeTest'`. What dependency do I need to add to my gradle file to resolve this error?

Comment: Support annotations, maybe?

Comment: @cricket_007 Do you mean `androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.1'`? I have this already...

Answer (score 1):

Have you gone through [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html#setup) documentation?

You need to add some of these dependencies based on your need.

```
dependencies {
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4'
  // Set this dependency to use JUnit 4 rules
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4'
  // Set this dependency to build and run Espresso tests
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
  // Set this dependency to build and run UI Automator tests
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
}
```

And add :

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

Comment: "Have you gone through this documentation?" Yes. That is the exact page that I linked in my question. And I have all of those dependencies defined and set `testInstrumentationRunner`.

Answer (score 1):

The filter annotation lives under the following dependency

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
```

If it's still not working please file a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Test%20Support%20Library%20bug).

Edit: The issue is that it was introduced in version 0.5 so you have to update your dependency.

Answer (score 0):

For AndroidX:

`import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest`

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/filters/LargeTest